# nHibernate Criteria query with missing mapping

Tags: nhibernate, mapping, criteria

I'm trying to do the following thing:

```
ICriteria criteriaSelect = 
                session 
                .CreateCriteria(typeof(Employees)) 
                .CreateCriteria("Orders") 
               ; 
var test = criteriaSelect.List<Orders>();
```

With:

```
public class Orders{ 
    public virtual int OrderID { get; private set;} 
} 

public class Employees{ 
    public virtual int EmployeeID { get; private set;} 
    public virtual IList<Orders> Orders { get; private set; } 
}
```

And I get the error: "No persister for: Employees".

Please note that for decoupling reason, I don't want Orders to 
reference Employees.

Thanks for your help, 
Stephane

Comment: have you added your Employee mapping file to nhibernate config before build your session factory ?

Answer (score 0):

The Criteria API is for indicating the specification you want during the query.  You will need to establish mappings for your entities using either the older hbm.xml files or using Fluent NHibernate.  See chapter 5 on [Basic O/R Mapping](https://www.hibernate.org/hib_docs/nhibernate/html/mapping.html) for more details.